# Objective-C Threads

Tags: objective-c

How in the world did I get this result:

```
2012-02-15 14:00:46.008 Test[3602:f803] 1: 0
2012-02-15 14:00:46.010 Test[3602:f803] 3: 1
2012-02-15 14:00:46.011 Test[3602:f803] 4: 3
2012-02-15 14:00:46.010 Test[3602:11703] 2: 2
```

From this code:

```
TestClass * test = [[TestClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"1: %i", test.value++);
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
     NSLog(@"2: %i", test.value++);
});
@synchronized(test) {
     NSLog(@"3: %i", test.value++);
}
NSLog(@"4: %i", test.value++);
```

My expectation would have been:

```
2012-02-15 14:00:46.008 Test[3602:f803] 1: 0
2012-02-15 14:00:46.010 Test[3602:f803] 3: 1
2012-02-15 14:00:46.011 Test[3602:f803] 4: 2
2012-02-15 14:00:46.010 Test[3602:11703] 2: 3
```

or even

```
2012-02-15 14:00:46.008 Test[3602:f803] 1: 0
2012-02-15 14:00:46.010 Test[3602:f803] 3: 1
2012-02-15 14:00:46.010 Test[3602:11703] 2: 2
2012-02-15 14:00:46.011 Test[3602:f803] 4: 3
```

since test.value was incremented in the log for step 2, yet it was not logged? wth?

Comment: Any log is essentially serial, so the GCD block incremented the value, but didn't get a chance to print it until an internal (somewhere in NSLog) mutex allowed it to. **Multithreaded coding is non-intuitive**.

Comment: NSLog() in particular takes an exclusive lock on the logging engine. You can get somewhat more timely results using `printf()`, but your log lines may intermix.

Comment: While I think @Costique and @dasblinkenlight's comments are the correct answer in this case, do note that `test.value++` is wildly non-atomic (even if `test` is an "atomic" ivar). So #2 and #4 could collide and corrupt `value`. Even just `i++` isn't thread-safe in C. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680097/ive-heard-i-isnt-thread-safe-is-i-thread-safe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is time between the moment a call to `NSLog` is initiated and the moment when `NSLog` writes a string to the log. It may get pre-empted during that time, and so another thread could potentially sneak in its log entry before this instance of `NSLog` wakes up.

Here is a possible sequence of events that leads to your printout:

1. Thread A calls `NSLog(@"2: %i", test.value++);`, 2 goes on the stack as `%i`'s parameter, and 3 is written to `test.value`
2. Thread A gets pre-empted in the middle of preparing log's output
3. Main thread calls `NSLog(@"4: %i", test.value++);`, 3 goes on the stack as `%i`'s parameter, and 4 is written to `test.value`
4. Main thread writes `4: 3` to the log without being pre-empted
5. Thread A wakes up, takes 2 from the stack, formats its output, and writes `2: 2` to the log

Comment: where's the stack for %i's parameter being held?

Comment: @MatisseVerDuyn Each thread has its own stack region. This region is used by the compiled code to pass parameters to functions: the caller pushes parameters onto the stack, and the function being called pops their values off the stack (this is an oversimplification, but the full description would not fit in 500 characters). So your function pushes `@"2: %i"` and 2 onto the stack, `NSLog` picks up `@"2: %i"`, parses it, detects the `%i`, and pops 2 off the stack.